# How to give an alert when the receiver accepts the call?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing one Phone Application. In that my requirement is when the receiver accepts the call then I give an alert(a small sound) at caller(who is calling) side that caller thinks that receiver accepts the call.

For this I am using the following code for an alert method when call is connected:

```
public void callConnected(int callId) 
{   
    Alert.startAudio(GetTone.TUNE, 80);
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("====================Start Audio: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Alert.stopAudio();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

But I am not getting any TUNE sound.

Am I did correct or not?
If not give some solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the sound from this small code:

```
public static short frequency = 1046;
public static short duration = 200;
public static int volume = 100;
```

and whenever I want the sound call this method:

```
public static void beepSound() 
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {                
            Alert.startAudio(new short[]{frequency, duration}, volume);                 
        }
    });
}
```

Then I got the beep sound.